# Texto para grid sin datos - Genexus Ev2 U7

Tags: java, genexus

En un webpanel, dónde tengo un par de grids que me muestran datos, necesito que, cuando alguno de los grids no muestre datos, me aparezca un texto (algo como "no hay datos para mostrar") en vez de que salga el encabezado de ese grid.

Ej: Que aparezca algo así, cuando no tengo datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Grilla con datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He buscado por todos lados, y hasta preguntado a la gente de Artech, pero no he encontrado nada.
Alguien sabe si se puede hacer y cómo ?

Gracias.

Comment: Debes poner el código que tienes o alguna captura de pantalla, para entender mejor lo que quieres lograr y poderte dar una respuesta

Comment: Ya edité la pregunta y le puse unas imágenes ilustrativas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jam,

Creo que la mejor forma es poner el grid en una tabla, y el texto en otra. en el evento refresh (o donde carga los datos) hacer tabla1.visible = true y tabla2.visible = false si hay registros o el contrario si no.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, ahora, me queda otra duda; cómo "pregunto" si la grilla tiene registros ? Gracias.

Comment: Buenas, podrías usar la propiedad "record count"
http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?8757,RecordCount%20Property

Comment: Sandro, hice lo que me sugeriste, pero me sigue mostrando el cabezal de la grilla. Alguna otra sugerencia para que me oculte todo ?

Answer (score 2):

Una posible solución, que me gusta porque no implica programación y con muy poco trabajo puede usarse en todos los grids de tu aplicación, es usar CSS para que aparezca un texto dentro del grid, cuando este no tiene filas.

La solución se basa en utilizar la [pseudo-clase ":empty"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty) sobre la tabla HTML que se genera para el grid, y algunas opciones de extensibilidad que tienen los themes GeneXus.

Si, por ejemplo, tu grid tiene la clase `WorkWith`, debes incluir una clase Custom en tu theme con el nombre `"WorkWith tbody:empty:after"`.
Para agregarla, haces click derecho sobre el nodo Custom y seleccionas la opción "Add Class" del menú contextual.

Luego, configura las propiedades de la nueva clase de esta manera:

```
Display = block
Margin Top = 50px
Margin Bottom = 50px
Margin Left = 20px
Custom CSS Properties = content('<Aquí va el texto que quieres que aparezca>')
```

Puedes ajustar los valores de los márgenes u otras propiedades estéticas de la clase a tu gusto, para que el mensaje tenga el diseño que prefieras.

Esta solución que te propongo no oculta el cabezal, así que sólo te servirá si para ti es aceptable que aparezca el cabezal cuando no hay datos. Una alternativa es seguir los pasos que proponen en otra respuesta, en la que sugieren ocultar y mostrar controles dependiendo de la cantidad de registros del grid.

Comment: Gracias ncardeli, ya lo solucioné cómo me comentaron más arriba, poniendo 2 tablas, y ocultando una de ellas según el grid tenga o no registros. Igual lo tengo en cuenta para otra vez.
Saludos.